# Edge of factoring technology?

Tags: cryptography, factoring

Schneier in 1996's Applied Cryptography says:

> "Currently, a 129-decimal-digit
>   modulus is at the edge of factoring
>   technology"

In the intervening 15 years has anything much changed?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Current_state_of_the_art

Comment: Perfect, want to submit that as an answer?

Comment: A maintained answer on Cryptography.SE: [How big an RSA key is considered secure today?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1978/18298)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please consult Wikipedia before posting a question. You can still ask about the Wikipedia article, of course.

See [Integer factorization: Current state of the art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Current_state_of_the_art).

Comment: I actually did but searched for the wrong thing. Finding nothing I turned to here instead and am glad I did so. By engaging with you here and following up on the links I learned so much more than I would have if I'd just found the answer myself. Awarding this the answer as it comes closest to answering my original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The same algorithm is used for factoring, the Number-Field Sieve. It's probably been optimized further. But the main difference between now and then is computing power. Since the asymptotic running-time of the NFS is "known", you can even extrapolate into the future (assuming your favorite version of Moore's law).

Comment: Thanks - I cannot vote up as I don't have enough rep. I hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 3):

For factoring RSA moduli (product of two large distinct primes), the Number Field Sieve is still king.  It has two phases: a parallelizable sieving phase where we look for polynomials, then a non-parallelizable matrix reduction step that is usually done on a large computer.

If quantum computers ever become practical, they can factor integers via [Shor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) in polynomial time.  In fact, this is the only known compelling application for them, but it's enough for the military to spend millions in the U.S. funding research on quantum computers.

**Note:** Peter Shor is a frequent contributor on this site.

Comment: It's Shor, not Schor.

Comment: Blah, sorry.  I had "Schorr" originally (probably confused with Claus Schnorr, another cryptographer) and I "fixed" the spelling from "Schorr" to "Schor".  Thanks to J.M.

Comment: Thanks - I cannot vote up as I don't have enough rep. I hope you'll understand.

Comment: @noonand: No problem, I appreciate the comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well understanding, that your question targets the factorization problem: Guess the effective strength of public key cryptography lies in the method, i.e. that you can establish private sessions without preexisting secret. E.g. you could use a transient public key with ´sufficient´ length to exchange a secondary set of keys, which even the public key of is only known to your counterpart. So nobody else knows about a secondary modulus and there is no factorization problem, at all, as the ´man in the middle´ will see nothing but a stream of white noise.